# Find character occurrences in SQL at the end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i find the occurrences of 'e' **at then end only** of a string in sql?

For example:

abcdeee, occurrences: 3

aecdeae, occurrences: 1

Thanks.

Comment: What SQL have you attempted so far?

Comment: while loop and checking each character

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: Can you either post the SQL you have tried or any of the code you are using to attempt this.

Comment: you have any numbers in this field? or other characters outside a-z

Answer (score 1):

The goal is going to be to avoid looping if at all possible, since SQL Server works much better with sets of data rather than processing things sequentially. With that in mind, I would generate a virtual table that gives you all of the counts that you might find. To be safe, it should be the same length as your column. In my example, I've stopped at 10 characters. I use a CTE to generate the virtual table. You can use a variable in there instead of the hard-coded 'e' of course. Also, the `CAST()`s are important to avoid data type mismatches with the recursive CTE, but you may need to adjust them, especially if you're using `NVARCHAR`.

```
;WITH CTE_Characters AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('e' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS my_char, 1 AS cnt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CAST(my_char + 'e' AS VARCHAR(10)), cnt + 1
    FROM
        CTE_Characters
    WHERE
        cnt <= 9
)
SELECT
    MT.my_string,
    MAX(CTE.cnt) AS number_of_occurrences
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN CTE_Characters CTE ON REVERSE(MT.my_string) LIKE CTE.my_char + '%'
GROUP BY
    MT.my_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop that will count the instances of 'e' on the end of an incoming string:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(50) = 'abcdeee'; --incoming string
DECLARE @ctr int = 0; --to count instances
DECLARE @rts nvarchar(50) = REVERSE(@str); --reverse the incoming string to start from the end
DECLARE @ind int = CHARINDEX('e',@rts,1); --find the first instance of e

WHILE @ind = 1 --only continue to count consecutive instances
    BEGIN
        SET @ctr += 1;
        SET @rts = RIGHT(@rts,LEN(@rts)-1); --remove first character and re-run
        SET @ind = CHARINDEX('e',@rts,1); --find next e
    END

SELECT @ctr AS ctr
```